# Zabbix Docker- Unable to launch web console

Tags: docker, zabbix

I am running Dockerized Zabbix as per the instructions mentioned on [this link](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/installation/containers). However, I am unable to launch the web console on this URL- `http://localhost:8080/zabbix`. The container port is `80` and the host port is `8080`. I keep getting `404`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Zabbix container port is also `8080`. I found this out by doing some trial and error by connecting to the Zabbix container with `docker exec -i -t <CONTAINER_ID> bash` and doing a curl to `http://localhost:8080/zabbix`.

I hope it helps!

Cheers, 
Kunal